# How to create an event handler on c# for an html search form?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm a newbie on c# and I am stuck on a very basic step to get my application to work. I have this custom HTML search form that I built(not the asp.net search bar provided by visual studios), but I don't know how to call it from c# so when the user enters a search in the application the c# code runs.

I am trying to implement a spelling suggestion in the search bar, so when the user types (whatever value) and search for it, c# checks the database for possible suggestion (those suggestion should be display after the search is submitted) if they didn't spell it right like google(did you mean).

what c# handler should I use for a search form???

My html code is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<form id="locationSearchForm">
   <label for="locationSearchInput" />
   <input name="" id="locationSearchInput" placeholder="Search by name, region,     food ..." value="" type="search" />
</form>
```

So my `c#` should be start something like:

```
protected void locationSearchInput_KeyDown(object sender KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
   {
    // Any suggestions
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this , you must try and implement one of them and then ask for specific issues that may arise.

One way to do this is to create a div below the search textbox like an extension, the way Google does it and then handle the suggestions clientside.
You do not want to make a round trip to the server for each keypress. Google does not make suggestions after you press enter but as you type it.
Check how that is done through Ajax.

Also you will need to have a suggestions dataset on which the keypress will be matched and the matching suggestion will be appended to the list in the div.

Hope this gives you a direction.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are adding the html code in aspx file and want to use code behind logic for that. So better use the asp:Label and add the event

Or

User ajax autocomplete extender and create webmethod or any service method to call for autocomplete action (getting the data based upon typed text). Refer this link

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/05/ajax-autocompleteextender-sample.html